# Input error in Contour plot of a Sphere Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am trying to plot a sphere function using contour plot, but I keep getting the following error.

```
??? Error using ==> Z must be size 2x2 or greater.
```

Error in is at this line of code:

```
contour(X1, X2, Z);
```

Here is the sphere function:

```
function ph = sphere(x)
         ph = sum(x.*x, 2);
end
```

Here is the code to plot the sphere using contour plot:

```
min = -25;
max = 25;
h = 25;
c= linspace(min, max, h); % Create the mesh
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(c, c); % Create the grid

Z = sphere(X1,X2);

figure;
icontour(X1, X2, Z);
```

I expect Z to return at least a 2x2 matrix. Z is supposed to be the height of the sphere and X1 is the x-axis and X2 is the y-axis.

How can I eliminate the error?

Comment: You've defined your function to take 1 argument, but you're passing 2...

Comment: That is how the function should be defined. If i pass one, say
z = sphere(X1), i still have this error:
"Z must be size 2x2 or greater".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, That is how the function should be defined. If i pass one, say z = sphere(X1), i still have this error: "Z must be size 2x2 or greater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `sum` in your `sphere` function. While `X1` and `X2` are `25x25` matrices, `ph`is a `25x1`vector. Try this:

```
function ph = sphere(x)

ph = x.*x;
```

In this case, your value `ph` will be of the same dimenion as your grid variables.

**Edit**

If you use your updated approach:

```
Z = arrayfun(@sphere, X1);
```

You will get constant lines because you just pass X1 to your `spheres` function. Which, in that case is the same as:

```
ph = sum(x.^2,2);
```

To get a sphere, you want to pass both arguments, `X1` and `X2`:

```
function ph = sphere(x1,x2)
     ph = sum(x1.*x2, 2);
end
```

And call:

```
Z = arrayfun(@sphere, X1, X2);
```

If you call your modified function like that, you'll get this result:

[image]

**Edit 2**

ATTENTION: If you are using `sphere` somewhere else in your script, you have to update each call to it to include two input arguments.

**Edit 3**

Depending on how carefully you implement this code, I would advise against using `sphere` as a name for a function, because of [Matlab's own function with that name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html).

Comment: I think it is working now. I use this statement:
Z = arrayfun(@sphere, X1);

Comment: if i edit the sphere function to take in two arguments, this line of code won't work:
eval = sphere(pop);

Comment: @ Schorsch i have included the code in your edit part of the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30758/discussion-between-user2179716-and-schorsch)