# How to plot a sphere function?

Tags: matlab, plot

I tried plotting a sphere [to look like this](http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO_files/Page1113.htm).

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760976/input-error-in-contour-plot-of-a-sphere-function-in-matlab) contains the code where i tried plotting.

That previous question was answered, but now I am having trouble plotting the sphere function as shown in the plot given by the link above.

**Edit**
This is the sphere function i am using:

```
function ph = sphereFN(x)
    ph = sum(x.*x, 2);

end
```

**Edit**
Outcome should look something like this:
[image]

NB: I have changed the function from sphere to sphereFN to avoid the conflict with the matlab sphere.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use [this sphere function](http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO_files/TestGO_files/TestCodes/sphere.m)? Also, it looks different from what you posted in your reply to @shoelzer

Comment: @Schorsch The code looks different,but basically doing the same thing. They all taking x, maybe as vector as input and summing. The sphere function i posted is the one i am using. It should not be modified. There is no reason, but basically trying to test i. I am not using [link](http:http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO_files/TestGO_files/TestCodes/sphere.m) this sphere. I am using the one i post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sphereFN` may not be doing what you expect it to do. It looks like you are trying to implement a [`sum of different powers`](http://infinity77.net/global_optimization/test_functions_nd_S.html) test based on this function:

[image: sodp]

However, your implementation as:

```
ph = sum(x.*x, 2);
```

does not resemble that function. How about using this as a starting point:

```
x = linspace(-1,1,25);

for I=1:size(x,2)
    for J=1:size(x,2)
        s(I,J) = abs(x(I))^2 + abs(x(J))^3;
    end
end

[xx,yy] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,25));  

surfc(xx,yy,s)
```

As your are in essence describing a 2D problem, this crude implementation of the function will suffice. You can put the nested `for`-loops into a function called `sum_of_different_powers_2D` (for example) and call it, passing the vector `x`.

**Edit**

You may get a shape that looks more like your intended surface by replace the command inside the nested `for`-loops with:

```
s(I,J) = abs(x(I))^2 + abs(x(J))^2;
```

This will resemble this function:

[image: sphere]

**Edit 2**

It is important to understand that `n` in the equation quoted above is the dimension of your problem. Which, as you showed, is `2`.

**Edit 3**

I recommend you use this function:

```
function ph = sphereFN(x)

for I=1:size(x,2)
    for J=1:size(x,2)
        ph(I,J) = abs(x(I))^2 + abs(x(J))^2;
    end
end

end
```

Comment: I have tried you suggestion but i am not getting the sphere shape as above. I am actually using this [link](http://infinity77.net/global_optimization/_images/math/fb5e12c8fdc92269e27e0a7a9d63834cfbe855a4.png), not the sum of different.

Comment: sorry you can check again. i am using n=2.

Comment: it still not giving me. How about my sphere function? is it not gonna work with just saying z = sphereF(X1) to get the third dimension and plot a contour?

Comment: i created your ph function in Edit 3 as a separate m-file and i am trying to call it in my program like this z = sphereFN(X1), but still telling me z must be atleast 2x2 or more. Is there anyway you can use the entire code i sent you with your function and see if it will come out they way we anticipating it?

Comment: @Schorschthat was a mistake from my typing. It has been rectified. what should the x input be? I tried using X1 from my code which is a 25 x 25.

Comment: @ Schorsch this will only plot the surface, how about the contour lines? when i check your answer, i run into this error:Attempted to access x(26); index out of bounds because numel(x)=25.

Comment: @ Schorsch yea, but i still have error. Can you just post the code that is working for you. I don't know if you have test on the code it sent you? Also please post the result here and let me see how it looks.

Comment: @ Schorsch thanks. i think is coming out now. Does your modified sphere function does the same i my original sphere function?

Comment: Sorry i am posting this here because my account cannot post new question. I have been trying all these days to plot contour of this function: function f=rosenbrock_func(x)
D = 2;
f=sum(100.*(x(:,1:D-1).^2-x(:,2:D)).^2+(x(:,1:D-1)-1).^2,2);
end
but could not and i need some help, that i why i am posting the question here. I tried to use the method of the sphere above but to no avail. Can you please help me out here please.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a built in sphere function and the documentation shows how to plot it.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html

Comment: I have seen that, but i am using this sphere function:
function ph = sphereFN(x)
    ph = sum(x.*x, 2);

Z = sphereFN(X1) % This evaluate the Z as the third dimension, but i kept on having Z must be atleast 2x2
    
end
if i use contour(X1,X2,Z);